# Angular Material - Scrolling issue for select component

Tags: ios, angular, angular-material, capacitor, mat-select

I am currently working on an app developed using Angular Material (v 9.2.0) and Ionic Capacitor. On iOS devices I am currently facing an issue with mat-select component.

As seen in the screenshot, once opened, the list of options doesn't scroll with the page.

[mat-select issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HpYj.png)

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Shardul Sane

Answer (score 1):

If you are using matTooltip directive for mat-option try to delete it. This did a trick for me.

upd. After fixing this issue in my code I've found [this reference](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15058) to the issue.